# Dynamically run method is not throwing an error but nothing is happening

Tags: c#

When I run the following code no errors are thrown but the method that is being called does not appear to run.

```
string Class = Node.SelectSingleNode("class").InnerXml;
string[] Parameters = { Username, Password, Browser };

Type type = Type.GetType(Class);
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Case");

Thread userThread = new Thread(() => methodInfo.Invoke(obj, Parameters));
userThread.Start();
```

I have checked that the Class variable contains the right string, and it does. I have also run methodInfo.Invoke(...) without starting a new thread but I ran into the same problem.

**Edit:**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace Example
{

    class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string Class = "OtherClass";
            string[] Parameters = { "User", "123", "IE" };

            Type type = Type.GetType(Class);
            Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("MyFunction");

            methodInfo.Invoke(obj, Parameters)

        }
    }

    class OtherClass
    {

        public static void MyFunction(string[] Parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Parameters[0]);
        }

    }

}
```

I expect to see the console print out "User" but instead I get nothing. Having debugged the code, the error appears to occur because of "Object obj = ...".

As the following code only outputs as far as "1.1"

```
Console.WriteLine("1");
Type type = Type.GetType(Class);
Console.WriteLine("1.1");
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
Console.WriteLine("1.2");
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Case");
Console.WriteLine("2");
```

Comment: Have you debugged the thread where the method is supposed to run? How do you know it's not throwing an error?

Comment: have you tested by adding a breakpoint inside the `Case` method?

Comment: The only thing I can spot that is "wrong" is your `Parameters` should be an `object[]` for passing into `methodInfo.Invoke(...)`, but that shouldn't cause any issues.  Can you make an MCVE demonstrating this issue?

Comment: @xxbbcc I have tried running the program without the 'Thread' code and the same problem outlined in my original post occurs

Comment: @adiga Using breakpoints I found that the problem appears to be occurring somewhere between: "Type type ..." and "MethodInfo methodInfo = ..."

Comment: @ConorMcCauley are you getting any exceptions? If yes, you need to post them here.

Comment: @Amy See latest edit.

Comment: @adiga No exceptions.

Comment: Your function is static. You don't pass the object when invoking a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a couple of things wrong here. I don't know why you said you didn't get any exceptions.

- You have to mention the full Namespace while using `GetType()`.
- Invoke expects an `object[]`
- You don't need to create an instance while calling a `static` method (This won't throw an error if you do)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string classNameSpace = "Example.OtherClass";
    string[] Parameters = { "User", "123", "IE" };

    Type type = Type.GetType(classNameSpace);
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("MyFunction");

    methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { Parameters })
}
```

Comment: This worked. Errors were thrown at a later point but the initial issue was resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Update: everything works fine now. Also, the reason I wasn't getting any exceptions was because I'd accidentally left that part of the code inside of a try-catch statement.